# Generate random date in rust from date interval

Tags: date, rust, random

I want to generate a random date from an interval using `rand::StdRng`. Currently I'm able to generate random date like that:

```rust
pub fn random_date(rng: &mut StdRng) -> Date {
    rng.sample(Standard)
}
```

But this approach generates any date, which is not within a given interval. How to randomly generate dates in interval? Say, I want to get a date from 2000 to 2010.

I use [time::Date](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.Date.html)

Comment: Generate an int and treat as seconds?  use mod to limit it to the duration of the range.  I'm not rusty, that's just one way it could be done in C, C++, C#, PHP, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify which `Date` your code works for? `gen_range` should work for that same type.

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that accepts 3 parameters:

- mutable reference to a random number generator
- start date
- end date

The function calculates the duration between the dates (`days_in_range`) and uses that to limit the production of a random integer `rng.gen_range(0..days_in_range)`, finally it adds that integer to the start date  `start + Duration::days(random_days)` thus producing a random date within a date range.

```
use chrono::{NaiveDate, Duration};
use rand::Rng;

pub fn random_date_in_range(rng: &mut rand::rngs::ThreadRng, start: NaiveDate, end: NaiveDate) -> NaiveDate {
    let days_in_range = (end - start).num_days();
    let random_days: i64 = rng.gen_range(0..days_in_range);
    start + Duration::days(random_days)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't specify which date i use, but i think the same approach is possible for the time::Date too.

Comment: The logic above is dependent on calculation of days, so if you want smaller time units you would need to rework to suit.